# В чем проблема?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. Собственно вот сам скрипт:

```
<?php

$url = "http://site.ru"; //URL для накрутки
$proxies = "proxy.txt"; //Файл с проксями

function connect($url, $proxy){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; ru; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008070208');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "$proxy");
    $res=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

$proxies = file($proxies);
foreach($proxies as $proxy){
    connect($url, $proxy);
}

?>
```

Этот скрипт должен накручивать посетителей на сайте. Ошибок нет, но что-то не хочет.. В чем проблема? Давайте попробуем решить.

З.Ы. От ваших вариантов не откажусь +

Answer (score 3):

Таким способом можно накрутить только количество обращений к апачу, все счетчики работают на javascript и не будут накручиваться.

Answer (score 1):

```
$proxy = trim($proxy);
```

т.к. может сохраниться `\r`. Да и

```
var_dump(connect($url, $proxy));
```

не помешало бы показать.